# Is a file descriptor local to its process or global on Unix

Tags: c, unix, file-descriptor

```
int fd = socket(//arguments);
```

Can this descriptor be passed to another process via IPC and still be valid or is it local to the process that created it?

Comment: If it were global, how could different processes use the same descriptor numbers for the standard streams?

Comment: You are right I forgot that. Stupid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, file descriptors are local to the process.  When a process forks a child, however, the parent and child have the same file descriptor table.  This is great because it allows for IO redirection, which is a pretty handy trick.

Answer (score 7):

File descriptors are local to the process. For instance, every process will have its standard input, output, and error on file descriptors 0, 1, and 2.

[It is possible to pass a file descriptor to another process over a UNIX domain socket.](https://keithp.com/blogs/fd-passing/) When this is done, each process will have a copy of the file descriptor, possibly under a different FD number. It's a kind of messy API, though, and is rarely used.